# Resize image after ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, image, resize

So, in the AJAX I append an image to a dynamically generated element, and tried to resize it using .css from jQuery, but the image is not resizing. How do I resize it?

Here is an example:

```
$("#lalala").append('<div class="blah"></div>');
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data)
    {
        $(".blah").append('<img src="images/"'+data[img]+'">');
        $(".blah img").css({'width':'120px' , 'height':'120px'});
    }
```

Comment: Can you console.log($('.blah img')); and tell me if that returns anything

Comment: No, the code is fine, it appears the img element is receiving the css, as i see in the element inspector. But the image is not resizing.

Comment: That's odd, if you can actually see it in the element inspector it should just update. Did you try some very small or large sizes (like 5px) and see if that does anything. -- You can also try setting the size via $('.blah img').width(120).height(120); and see if that has an effect

Comment: Strange, it worked. In the element inspector it looks just the same, with the same style.

Comment: are you sure that a div with the class blah exists on your page.  This line `$("#lalala").append("<div class="blah"></div>");` is not valid.  It needs to be  `$("#lalala").append("<div class='blah'></div>");`

Comment: I read somewhere that the image needs to be loaded before the changes. Maybe width and height functions have add css in a different way. Would like to understand why one worked and the other didn't...

Comment: So, element is adding to the DOM? btw. you have little typo after src, it should be <img src="/'+data[img]+'"> (slash after opening quotation mark). But into the question. Try this way: $('<img src="/'+data[img]+'">).appendTo('.blah').css({'width':'120px' , 'height':'120px'});

Comment: @Jacob it's just an example, I mistyped it. The solution given by Wouter Rutgers worked, I just don't know why it worked =/

Comment: Just corrected the typos.

Comment: My bad of course, should be - appendTo($('.blah')) * if you would like doing this way

Comment: I'm starting to think that appending to appended elements is not a good idea. Everything I appended with the Ajax is not working as it should, but looking beautiful in the element inspector and in the DOM source code.

Comment: My boss gave me a static site to turn into a widget (he did it because i suck with visual stuff, so he gave me everything ready). And there is a div that i append with ajax too, that was not inheriting the parent's size, different from the static version (they are exactly equal, at least in the generated HTML)